# Best way to handle similar components in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component

Consider that there are two similar components in a project. One includes only extra button and other features are totally same. What is the best way to create those components? I made an example you can understand what I meant more clearly [Example for similar Components](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-allen-72yqt) (please omit minor mistakes like not using key props etc.) For sure the example can be more complicated.

Some solutions that I thought;

1- I can pass control prop and and use ternary operation to render button.(I think it causes unnecessary checks)

2- Create two separate components(what I did in example). (It does not seem DRY)

3- HOC can be used but I could not figure it out.

If there is HOC solution or other sensible please share, thanks in advance

Also I share the code;

```
const SelectionCard = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Card}>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const AlmostSameCard = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Card}>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button>{name}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

*edit: Most of the answers focus on example that I gave. What should we do edge cases like too much conditions, huge data for render etc.*

Comment: Pass a props and use `condition rendering` seems simple enough.

Comment: For this example yes simple,however; consider that there are 4 different props, should I put 4 different if block or switch?

Comment: there is a need of control prop if you need to use only one component and yes use ternary check.

Answer (score 1):

## Conditional elements

A component will render based on the props you pass. You should render the elements that make sense for that component. But ensure that the component doesn't get bloated from big conditional sections.

Your card component can have optional elements like date, text, label, tags. Just render the parts that have content conditionally.

```
const SelectionCard = ({ name, buttonText }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Card}>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      {buttonText && <button>{buttonText}</button>}
    </div>
  );
};
```